# Secure postfix smtp from spammer

Tags: postfix, smtp, smtp-auth

I run on Centos 5 with Parallels Plesk 12 and look for to secure my smtp server.
When I watch at log, I see some strange line like that, which I supposed it's hack connexion.

Has someone any idea on how to secure my server from this ?

```
Oct 10 00:10:45 $myhost$ postfix/smtpd[5736]: warning: XX-XXX-XX-XX-
SFBA.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[XX.XXX.XX.XX]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed:
authentication failureHas someone any idea on how to secure my server from this ?
```

(Case 1)

```
Oct 10 00:10:45 myhost postfix/smtpd[5736]: warning: XX-XXX-XX-XX-
SFBA.hfc.comcastbusiness.net[XX.XXX.XX.XX]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed:
authentication failure
```

(Case 2)

```
Oct 10 18:34:11 myhost postfix/qmgr[15890]: 34FEE24FD3: from=<>, size=17347, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 10 18:34:11 myhost postfix/qmgr[15890]: 79A9224FD2: from=<>, size=17353, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 10 18:34:11 myhost postfix/smtp[17264]: certificate verification failed for mail.opencamp.fr[92.222.41.176]:25: self-signed certificate
Oct 10 18:34:11 myhost postfix/smtp[17264]: 79A9224FD2: to=<noreply@opencamp.fr>, relay=mail.opencamp.fr[XX.XXX.XX.XX]:25, delay=20963, delays=20963/0.07/0.11/0.04, dsn=4.2.2, status=deferred (host mail.opencamp.fr[XX.XXX.XX.XX] said: 452 4.2.2 Mailbox full (in reply to end of DATA command))
Oct 10 18:34:13 myhost postfix/smtp[17263]: certificate verification failed for mail.opencamp.fr[92.222.41.176]:25: self-signed certificate
Oct 10 18:34:13 myhost postfix/smtp[17263]: 34FEE24FD3: to=<noreply@opencamp.fr>, relay=mail.opencamp.fr[XX.XXX.XX.XX]:25, delay=20964, delays=20962/0.05/2/0.05, dsn=4.2.2, status=deferred (host mail.opencamp.fr[XX.XXX.XX.XX] said: 452 4.2.2 Mailbox full (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this sort of thing happens all the time with services connected to the Internet.  Take heart that the login failed.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard I hope to. But there is a way to ban this ip ?

Comment: http://www.fail2ban.org/

Comment: I understand for case 1 but I do not understand the message of case 2 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I achieved to protect the server from this ip by create iptables rules :

```
modify /etc/sysconfig/iptables to include rules :
-A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 25 -j DROP
-I INPUT -s XX.XXX.XX.XX -j DROP

>>> /etc/init.d/iptables save
>>> /etc/init.d/restart save
```